# Using PC mouse track pad for navigation

Tags: customization

I've been using a blender on a mac for a couple years now and navigation with the track pad worked perfectly. Now I'm trying to step up my game for rendering and physics simulations so I got myself a high powered gaming laptop. Problem is all the track pad inputs are all messed up on PC. Two fingers used to rotate in all directions now it only rotates sides and zooms up and down, its even worse wen i try to pan with shift, it only pans up and down and twists for side to side. Why are the Mac and PC track pads so different and ho do I make the PC track pad work as fluidly as the mac did.

Comment: This is really not a question about blender but about hardware configuration at the operating system level.

Comment: @cegaton the track pad gestures are the same across both computers but the way blender is reacting on pc is different. In other applications the track pad gestures are the same. Looking for any help finding blender configuration for track pad navigation